# More ergonomic alternative to nested defaultdicts

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, hashmap, defaultdict

I'm looking for a data structure that is:

- multidimensional
- indexable via hashes, like a dict (at least some of the dimensions are associated with objects, rather than with numeric indices)
- gigantic in size but very, very sparse (and reasonably memory efficient)
- returns a default value when the index doesn't exist

Right now I'm solving this using nested defaultdicts, but the ergonomics of looping over their `items()` is terrible, especially when I'm trying to operate over the second or third inner dimensions. Performance isn't great either.

I have considered using sparse-type Pandas data frames with multi-index columns instead, but those don't automatically return a default value (i.e., zero) when accessing missing indices, which happens all the time – and I'm not keen on wrapping everything in try/except blocks or using `df.get()` everywhere.

What are some alternative libraries/data structures/approaches I can consider?

Comment: Why won't you implement a thin wrapper around pandas with try/except blocks and a default value returned for missing values?

Comment: That's definitely an option, thanks @sophros! I just wondered if there are more obvious solutions that I'm unaware of